# Unable to get autoform 6.0 to populate with existing data

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

I've updated to simple-schema npm and installed autoform 6.0 however I seem unable to successfully generate forms for collections. I get this error `Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'mergedSchema' of undefined` and I have no idea what it is referring to since this is a new build so it shouldn't be referencing any old autoform or simple-schema packages.

Path:  `imports/ui/pages/candidate-registration/contact-information/contact-information.html`

```
<template name="App_contactInformation">
  {{#with profile}}
    {{firstName}}
      {{> quickForm collection=Profile id="updateProfile" type="update"}}
    {{/with}}
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

Path: `imports/ui/pages/candidate-registration/contact-information/contact-information.js`

```
import { Profile } from '/imports/api/profile/profile.js';
import './contact-information.html';

Template.App_contactInformation.onCreated(function () {
  this.autorun(() => {
    this.subscribe('private.profile');
  });
});

Template.App_contactInformation.helpers({
  profile() {
    var user = Profile.findOne({userId: Meteor.userId()});
    return user;
    }
});
```

Path: `imports/api/profile/server/publications.js`

```
// All profile-related publications

import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Profile } from '../profile.js';

Meteor.publish('private.profile', function() {
  if (!this.userId) {
    return this.ready();
  }
  return Profile.find({"userId": this.userId});
});
```

Comment: Is it okay that you have `{{> quickForm collection=Profile id="updateProfile" type="update"}}` collection=Profile with capital `P` and the method profile() in the template helpers has a lowecase `p`?

Comment: Another thing is that you need to be sure that you're that you're importing `imports/ui/pages/candidate-registration/contact-information/contact-information.js` in your client code and not the `.html` file. Otherwise, the Template code won't run and the helper `Profile` won't be available for the autoform in the collection attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are also using [aldeed:collection2-core](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2-core/blob/master/README.md) 
and have [attached your schema to your collection](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2-core/blob/master/README.md#attaching-a-schema-to-a-collection).  For example...

```
Books.attachSchema(Schemas.Book);
```